# angularjs expression didn't execute properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My HTML

```
{{myId}}
 <iframe width="100%" height="325" src="http://example.com/direct/?param={{myId}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The first {{myId}} worked but my second didn't. When I check my DOM it's still {{myId}}, why?

Answer (score 0):

Please try ng-src instead src:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="325" ng-src="http://example.com/direct/?param={{myId}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: While certainly a better option (if nothing else, then to avoid the initial bad server call), I'm not sure that's the reason the original example doesn't work.

Comment: So I guess you tried ng-src and it didn't work. The reason I think this is the cause of problem is because everything in "src" attribute will be loaded the  same time with angularjs library. There is a change that angular is not full loaded at that time. Then the page will not understand "{{myId}}"

When angular is full loaded, it will try to update value to first {{myId}},  but with the second {{myId}}, it is too late.